# Equality without using operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators, equality

I was asked if it was possible to compare two (say) lists without invoking operators, to determine if they were the same (or rather, contained the same elements).

I first entertained using

```
x in y
```

before I realised that it would not care for order, but for mere presence. Of course, if the lists were to contain purely numbers it would be trivial to do a modulus test or so, but lists can contain strings. (is didn't work either, but I didn't really expect it to, considering it tests identity...)

So I was wondering if it's (even) possible to pull off equality tests without using operators (==, !=)?

It was a mere rhetorical question, but it's been gnawing at me for some time and I've rather given up trying to solve it myself with my not-very extensive python knowledge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure it is, just bypass the operators and go straight for the `__eq__` special method:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x.__eq__(y)
True
>>> z = [42]
>>> x.__eq__(z)
False
```

You can also use the [`operator` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html):

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.eq(x, y)
True
>>> operator.eq(x, z)
False
```

In Python 2, you could use looping with [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and [`cmp()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp), with [`itertools.izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to make sure we don't ignore uneven lengths:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> not any(cmp(i, j) for i, j in izip_longest(x, y, fillvalue=object()))
True
>>> not any(cmp(i, j) for i, j in izip_longest(x, z, fillvalue=object()))
False
```

This works because `cmp()` returns `0` for values that are equal. `any()` returns `False` only if all results are false (e.g. 0).

Hell, go straight for `cmp()` *without* looping:

```
>>> not cmp(x, y)
True
>>> not cmp(x, z)
False
```

For Python 3 you'd have to create your own `cmp()` function, perhaps using `.__lt__` and `.__gt__` if you want to avoid the `<` and `>` operators too.

For lists with only integers, you can forgo the `cmp()` function and go straight to subtraction; let's use `map()` here and include the list lengths:

```
>>> not (len(x) - len(y)) and not any(map(lambda i, j: i - j, x, y))
True
>>> not (len(x) - len(z)) and not any(map(lambda i, j: i - j, x, z))
False
```

This works because `map()` zips up the values in the lists and passes these pairs to the first argument, a callable. That subtracts the values and only if the integers are equal do we get all `0` values and `any()` returns `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Martijn Pieters's answer, i could think of following options:

using XOR:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3]
result = "list equal"
if len(x)-len(y):
    result = "list not equal"
else:
    for i,j in zip(x,y):
        if i ^ j: 
            result = "list is not equal"
            break
print result
```

Using set:

```
if set(x).difference(set(y)):
    print "list not equal"
else:
    print "list equal"
```

Comment: The set difference won't work for lists with different elements repeated. `x = [1, 1, 2]` and `y = [1, 2, 2]`.